# How to get results from database tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:phones, phones_state and state

**phones:**

```
+------------------+
| phone_id | model |
+----------+-------+
| 1        | mot   |
| 2        | sam   |
+----------+-------+
```

**phones_state:**

```
+---------------------+
| phone_id | state_id |
+----------+----------+
| 2        | 1        |
| 2        | 3        |
| 2        | 5        |
| 1        | 1        |
+----------+----------+
```

**state:**

```
+------------------+
| state_id | name  |
+----------+-------+
| 1        | rec   |
| 2        | notre |
| 3        | res   |
| 4        | wait  |
| 5        | back  |
+----------+-------+
```

I want to get all phones that are in state 1 and not in state 5
How can I do this in mysql query?

Comment: Boiculese Iuli - Work on writing questions with better formatting, plus keep an eye on your previous questions and take time to accept the right answers. Not only you will be contributing to stackoverflow but also increasing your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.phone_id
from phones p
inner join phones_state ps on ps.phone_id = p.phone_id
group by p.phone_id
having sum(ps.state_id = 1) >= 1 and sum(ps.state_id = 5) = 0
```